# FFMPEG keeps converting without stopping when using HStack to combine a gif with an video while also using a scale2ref filter

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gif

I am trying to combine/merge a gif/image with a video to output a video that has both in one frame.
For that purpose i'm using FFMPEG on nodejs.
The filter I am using is Hstack and since the content can be dynamically sized so I am resizing the gif based on the parameters of video by running the scale2ref filter twice.

But it takes forever and doesn't stop. I think i would have to press CTRL+C in order to stop the terminal.

Here's the command:

```
ffmpeg -i in1.gif -i in2.mp4 -filter_complex
       "[0][1]scale2ref='oh*mdar':'if(lt(main_h,ih),ih,main_h)'[0s][1s];
        [1s][0s]scale2ref='oh*mdar':'if(lt(main_h,ih),ih,main_h)'[1s][0s];
        [0s][1s]hstack,setsar=1"   output.mp4
```

Here's what happens when i run this command in vscode terminal:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.gif -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]scale2ref='oh*mdar':'if(lt(main_h,ih),ih,main_h)'[0s][1s]; [1s][0s]scale2ref='oh*mdar':'if(lt(main_h,ih),ih,main_h)'[1s][0s]; [0s][1s]hstack,setsar=1"  Output2.mp4
```

And this is the output:

```
ffmpeg version git-2020-03-03-60b1f85 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray 
--enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 42.100 / 56. 42.100
  libavcodec     58. 73.102 / 58. 73.102
  libavformat    58. 39.101 / 58. 39.101
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 77.100 /  7. 77.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, gif, from 'input1.gif':
  Duration: 00:00:48.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 866 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: gif, bgra, 800x600, 1.25 fps, 1.25 tbr, 100 tbn, 100 tbc
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2020-03-06T02:02:36.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:36.71, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 949 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, 692 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 48k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-03-06T02:02:36.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 253 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-03-06T02:02:36.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Audio Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (gif) -> scale2ref:default (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> scale2ref:ref (graph 0)
  setsar (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #1:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp4 @ 00000253e9d58640] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2
[libx264 @ 00000253e9e60540] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 00000253e9e60540] MB rate (151200000) > level limit (16711680)
[libx264 @ 00000253e9e60540] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 00000253e9e60540] profile High, level 6.2, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 00000253e9e60540] 264 - core 159 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'Output2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.39.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 2240x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 28:9], q=-1--1, 24k tbn, 24k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.73.102 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-03-06T02:02:36.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Audio Handler
      encoder         : Lavc58.73.102 aac                                    ts/s dup=999 drop=0 speed=0.0062x
More than 1000 frames duplicated       0kB time=00:00:00.03 bitrate=   9.8kbiits/s dup=9999 drop=0 speed=0.0123xts/s dup=999 drop=0 speed=0.0062x                                            bits/s dup=99994 drop=0 speed=0.00757x
More than 10000 frames duplicated   2048kB time=00:00:00.46 bitrate=35747.8kbbits/s dup=444976 drop=0 speed=0.00696x    its/s dup=9999 drop=0 speed=0.0123x
More than 100000 frames duplicated  46592kB time=00:00:04.56 bitrate=83604.4kbits/s dup=99994 drop=0 speed=0.00757x
frame=447447 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  184320kB time=00:00:19.41 bitrate=77779.0kframe=448448 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  184576kB time=00:00:19.41 bitrate=77887.0kframe=449449 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  185088kB time=00:00:19.41 bitrate=78103.1kframe=450450 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  185344kB time=00:00:19.41 bitrate=78211.1kframe=451451 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  185856kB time=00:00:19.41 bitrate=78427.2kframe=452452 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  186112kB time=00:00:19.41 bitrate=78535.2kframe=453453 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  186624kB time=00:00:19.41 bitrate=78751.2kframe=454454 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  186880kB time=00:00:19.41 bitrate=78859.3kframe=455455 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  187392kB time=00:00:19.41 bitrate=79075.3kframe=456456 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  187648kB time=00:00:19.41 bitrate=79183.4kframe=457457 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  188160kB time=00:00:19.41 bitrate=79399.4kframe=457457 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  188160kB time=00:00:19.43 bitrate=79312.2kframe=459459 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  188928kB time=00:00:19.92 bitrate=77674.9kframe=460460 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  189440kB time=00:00:19.92 bitrate=77885.4kframe=460800 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  189440kB time=00:00:19.92 bitrate=77885.4kframe=461461 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  189696kB time=00:00:19.92 bitrate=77990.7kframe=462462 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  190208kB time=00:00:19.92 bitrate=78201.2kframe=463463 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  190464kB time=00:00:19.92 bitrate=78306.4kframe=464464 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  190976kB time=00:00:19.92 bitrate=78516.9kframe=465465 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  191488kB time=00:00:19.92 bitrate=78727.4kframe=466466 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  191744kB time=00:00:19.92 bitrate=78832.7kframe=467467 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  192256kB time=00:00:19.92 bitrate=79043.2kframe=468468 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  192512kB time=00:00:19.92 bitrate=79148.4kframe=469469 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  193024kB time=00:00:19.92 bitrate=79358.9kframe=470470 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  193536kB time=00:00:19.92 bitrate=79569.4kframe=471471 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  193792kB time=00:00:19.92 bitrate=79674.7kframe=472472 fps=164 q=33.0 size=  194304kB time=00:00:19.92 bitrate=79885.2kframe=473473 fps=163 q=33.0 size=  194560kB time=00:00:19.92 bitrate=79990.4kframe=474474 fps=163 q=33.0 size=  195072kB time=00:00:19.92 bitrate=80200.9kframe=475475 fps=163 q=33.0 size=  195328kB time=00:00:19.92 bitrate=80306.2kframe=476476 fps=163 q=33.0 size=  195840kB time=00:00:19.92 bitrate=80516.7kframe=477477 fps=163 q=33.0 size=  196096kB time=00:00:19.92 bitrate=80621.9kframe=478478 fps=163 q=33.0 size=  196352kB time=00:00:19.93 bitrate=80691.4kframe=479479 fps=163 q=33.0 size=  196352kB time=00:00:19.97 bitrate=80522.9kframe=480000 fps=163 q=33.0 size=  196352kB time=00:00:19.99 bitrate=80435.5kframe=480000 fps=163 q=33.0 size=  196352kB time=00:00:19.99 bitrate=80435.5kframe=480480 fps=163 q=33.0 size=  197376kB time=00:00:20.05 bitrate=80630.2kframe=481481 fps=163 q=33.0 size=  197632kB time=00:00:20.07 bitrate=80649.0kframe=483483 fps=163 q=33.0 size=  198656kB time=00:00:20.43 bitrate=79628.3kframe=484484 fps=163 q=33.0 size=  198912kB time=00:00:20.43 bitratMore than 1000000 frames duplicated330240kB time=00:00:41.59 bitrate=65035.7kbits/s dup=997468 drop=0 speed=0.0076x    
frame=1075200 fps=186 q=33.0 size=  330240kB time=00:00:44.79 bitrate=60390.0kbits/s dup=1074264 drop=0 speed=0.00773x
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do, as the phrase

> a video that has both in one frame

suggest to me that it should be in 1 frame (frames making up a video, so only one of those), which would only really be useful as some sort of stamp on the video, but not to the viewer, hence me suspecting you were meaning within the one video. The code below overlays a image on a video for X time. I hope that is what you are looking for.  I am sure you can adapt for any of the resizing you want to do, as the overlay bit appear to be what you are asking about, I hope I have understood.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4
```

I grabbed that from [another question on SE video production](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12105/add-an-image-overlay-in-front-of-video-using-ffmpeg).  It's explains moths of the options etc.

From the data you have provided, as you suspect, it looks like you have created a loop, and it will just keep duplicating, i.e. it is stuck in an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

The hstack picks the framerate of the first input, but the GIFs rate is probably too low, so ffmpeg has picked the timebase instead. So, set a manual rate instead for the GIF input.

```
-filter_complex "[0]fps=24[0v];[0v][1]scale2ref='oh*mdar':'if(lt(main_h,ih),ih,main_h)'[0s][1s]; [1s][0s]scale2ref='oh*mdar':'if(lt(main_h,ih),ih,main_h)'[1s][0s]; [0s][1s]hstack,setsar=1"
```